# Chrome Dev Tools (CSS) editing and saving

Tags: css, google-chrome

I need to change the color of some words in one category of the widget, I have seen the youtube video about Development Tools.

When I locate the part where I want to change, and I do the change in "Elements" (of Development tools) on the top right corner in the element.style {color:red;
}
but as following the video when I go to resources the changes I made is not there.

1. I can only edit in Elements, I cant save it
2. I can only save in Resources, I cant edit/add anything

can someone please help me how this dev tool suppose to work?

I can however edit/add AND save in the Sources, maybe I need to save the style sheet from Resources to Sources? is that what I am suppose to do?

Comment: [perhaps useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994435/copying-all-css-attributes-of-a-class-id-via-chrome-inspect#comment19316054_13994435)

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer, please vote for it and accept it. It is a way to thank the person who helped you and say to others what the correct answer is so it may be useful also for them. Here on stackoverflow we help each other by making and answering questions. @Wei Zhang

Answer (score 2):

As you said Chrome Dev Tools don't have the builtin function to save the code you edit, anyway there are a couple of Chrome extensions. The best in my opinion is **Tincr**.

You can find it here [Tincr](http://tin.cr/)

Then you can also find a tutorial here: http://addyosmani.com/blog/lets-tincr-bi-directional-editing-and-saving-with-the-chrome-devtools/.

Basically you

1. install the extension,
2. then you select the application type between: Ruby on Rails, Chrome Extension, Atlassian Plugin and Configuration file,
3. then you can add the root directory of your project.

   When you are done, if you edit something using Google Chrome Dev Tools, the changes will be saved automatically to the source files and there is also a live reload function, so you don't have to press the refresh button or F5 to reload the page after changes.

Comment: If you are satisfied by my answer, please vote for it. @Wei Zhang

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit files on the server through the developer tools and changes will not stay after a refresh.

Comment: yes, but locally you can by using a Chrome extension. Usually people develop websites locally, so it's alright. When you are done you just upload it to the ftp server. By using Tincr for example when you edit something in Chrome Dev Tools in the element panel, your changes will be saved to the actual files, no need to go to sources and edit from there or open directly the file. @florija

Comment: I did not know that, but thanks, it may be useful for my next project :)

Answer (score 0):

An updated answer as of March 2013, you can now save changes (JS and CSS, not DOM) from within Dev Tools.

http://remysharp.com/2012/12/21/my-workflow-never-having-to-leave-devtools/