# Copying all css attributes of a class/id via chrome inspect

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there a way to quickly copy all of the css code of the inspected element in google chrome?

I found that while designing, it's sometimes easier to change the css on-the-fly via inspect to figure out correct pixel distances, rather than changing in the code and refreshing the page.

Does that capability even exists?

Comment: You could select the element and then copy all the CSS in the computed styles...

Comment: There was a good screencast at [breakpoint](http://addyosmani.com/blog/), [I think this one](http://addyosmani.com/blog/the-breakpoint-episode1/) where they showed how to enable saving the modified style sheet from the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to steveax's comment I was able to find the answer, which I will share with you

Once the inspected element has been edited, going to the sources tab and choosing the appropriate CSS where that element is defined, the edited attributes will appear there, which you can copy regularly..

Obviously, a copy straight from the style window would be more comfortable..

Comment: Glad the link was useful. If you're developing locally, I think [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) is the ticket, esp. If you've got the monitor space to have the browser window(s) and your editor visible at the same time. Even when using Sass, the reloads are almost instantaneous.